# Finding the distance of points to an axis

Tags: python, numpy, linear-algebra

I have an array of points in 3D Cartesian space:

```
P = np.random.random((10, 3))
```

Now I'd like to find their distances to a given axis and on that given axis

```
Ax_support = array([3, 2, 1])
Ax_direction = array([1, 2, 3])
```

I've found a solution that first finds the vector from each point that is perpendicular to the direction vector... I feel however, that it is really complicated and that for such a standard problem there would be a numpy or scipy routine already out there (as there is to find the distance between points in `scipy.spatial.distance`)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I would be surprised to see such an operation among the standard operations of numpy/scipy. What you are looking for is the projection distance onto your line. Start by subtracting `Ax_support`:

```
P_centered = P - Ax_support
```

The points on the line through 0 with direction `Ax_direction` with the shortest distance in the L2 sense to each element of P_centered is given by

```
P_projected = P_centered.dot(np.linalg.pinv(
             Ax_direction[np.newaxis, :])).dot(Ax_direction[np.newaxis, :])
```

Thus the formula you are looking for is

```
distances = np.sqrt(((P_centered - P_projected) ** 2).sum(axis=1))
```

Yes, this is exactly what you propose, in a vectorized way of doing things, so it should be pretty fast for reasonably many data points.

Note: If anybody knows a built-in function for this, I'd be very interested!

Comment: Why `pinv`? It may be correct, but isn't it better to get the projected vector as `P_projected = Ax_direction * np.dot(P_centered, Ax_direction) / np.dot(Ax_direction, Ax_direction)`?

Comment: Well, one has `np.linalg.pinv(Ax_direction[np.newaxis, :]) == Ax_direction[:, np.newaxis] / np.dot(Ax_direction, Ax_direction)`. So it's the same. Possible personal bias: I often have to project onto higher dimensional subspaces, so I wrote the general solution. There is no difference in performance in this case.

Comment: Ok, I was wondering about the pinv as well, but now that I understand it (quite some reading ;-) I see how it works. I see now how this problem is simple enough to not need an extra scipy implementation, although it would be nice to get rid of the large arrays in between. But if even Jamie does not know an existing function for that, then it must not exist ;-).

Comment: What order of magnitude are we talking about here? How many points are there? There is always the possiblity to regroup certain operations, e.g.: `projector_to_orthogonal = np.eye(3) - np.linalg.pinv(Ax_direction[np.newaxis, :]).dot(Ax_direction[np.newaxis, :])`. With this operator you get the distance vectors directly: `distance_vectors = P_centered.dot(projector_to_orthogonal)`. It all depends on dataset size

Comment: (The previous comment is to address the issue of *large arrays in between*)

Answer (score 1):

It's been bothering me that something like this does not exist, so I added [`haggis.math.segment_distance`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest/api.html#haggis.math.segment_distance) to the library of utilities I maintain, [`haggis`](https://haggis.readthedocs.io/en/latest).

One catch is that this function expects a line defined by two points rather than a support and direction. You can supply as many points and lines as you want, as long as the dimensions broadcast. The usual formats are many points projected on one line (as you have), or one point projected on many lines.

```
distances = haggis.math.segment_distance(
        P, Ax_support, Ax_support + Ax_direction,
        axis=1, segment=False)
```

Here is a reproducible example:

```
np.random.seed(0xBEEF)
P = np.random.random((10,3))
Ax_support = np.array([3, 2, 1])
Ax_direction = np.array([1, 2, 3])
d, t = haggis.math.segment_distance(
        P, Ax_support, Ax_support + Ax_direction,
        axis=1, return_t=True, segment=False)
```

`return_t` returns the location of the normal points along the line as a ratio of the line length from the support (i.e., `Ax_support + t * Ax_direction` is the location of the projected points).

```
>>> d
array([2.08730838, 2.73314321, 2.1075711 , 2.5672012 , 1.96132443,
       2.53325436, 2.15278454, 2.77763701, 2.50545181, 2.75187883])

>>> t
array([-0.47585462, -0.60843258, -0.46755277, -0.4273361 , -0.53393468,
       -0.58564737, -0.38732655, -0.53212317, -0.54956548, -0.41748691])
```

This allows you to make the following plot:

```
fig, ax = plt.subplots(subplot_kw={'projection': '3d'})

ax.plot(*Ax_support, 'ko')
ax.plot(*Ax_support + Ax_direction, 'ko')

start = min(t.min(), 0)
end = max(t.max(), 1)
margin = 0.1 * (end - start)
start -= margin
end += margin

ax.plot(*Ax_support[:, None] + [start, end] * Ax_direction[:, None], 'k--')
for s, te in zip(P, t):
    pt = Ax_support + te * Ax_direction
    ax.plot(*np.stack((s, pt), axis=-1), 'k-')
    ax.plot(*pt, 'ko', markerfacecolor='w')
ax.plot(*P.T, 'ko', markerfacecolor='r')
plt.show()
```

[image]